# Get the time stamp format of time in python

Tags: python

How can i get this format of time in python
is there any suggestion about it

```
var ti = Date.now() + parseFloat(Math.random().toFixed(8))
```

```
1609193057063.8418
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.now().timestamp())
```

Or simpler:

```
import time

print(time.time())

Which will output:
```

> `1609193535.115763`

You can then, using slicing, cut the decimals at the end or just use the `decimal` stdlib to aproximate the last 4 decimals.

Comment: how to add the dot at the last 4